# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'| python-mysql

Tags: python, mysql, import, xampp

i have this error:

```
import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

I already install via pip3 mysql and mysql-connector
and of course also call import mysql.connector

im using xampp version 8.0.0 in my m1 I don't know if that will be the problem

[pip3 list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOJ1G.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVZob.jpg)

Comment: Please post the pip3 list and errors as text (using code blocks) in the questions instead of images. You may have more than one python installed, so pip3 installs in one and you run the other. In your script, before the bad import do, `import sys;print(sys.executable)` to see which python you are using. Then, using the full path of that python, do `/path/to/python3 -m pip list` to list _that_ python's packages. Are they the same?

Comment: omg ty! i change the  python version in vs and works! thanksss! 